# Totally unimodular matrices and identity matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, total-unimodularity

I know that if a matrix $A$ is Totally Unimodular (TU), then the matrix $(A\; I)$ is unimodular. Can I then say that the matrix $(A\; -I)$ is also TU? ($I$ is the identity block matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how one does matrices in LaTeX, so I will use Matlab notation. $A-I$ need not be TU: consider the almost-permutation matrix $A =[ [0,1,0] ~~ [1,0,0] ~~ [0,0,-1] ]$. This is clearly unimodular, and it's not too difficult to check and see it is also TU. However, $A-I = [ [-1, 1,0] ~~ [1,-1,0] ~~ [0,0,-2] ]$. If we consider the bottom-right 2x2 corner, we have $[[-1,0] ~~[0,-2]]$, which has determinant 2; thus $A-I$ is not TU.

Comment: Hi Eric: if you right click and "show as TeX" you can see how I do the following matrix: $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\ 1 &0&0\\0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Wow, that's much easier than anything else I've seen… do you know what package has the pmatrix environment?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the specifics... it's just always worked when I tried it!

Comment: @EricStucky It's in amsmath, I think. (I always include amsmath, so there's a small chance it's part of LaTeX itself, but I don't think so.)